# Retrying systemd when condition failed

Tags: linux, systemd

I have a systemd service which checks external media is mounted on starting.

```
[Unit]
Description=My App
ConditionPathIsMountPoint=/mnt/sdcard

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/opt/myapp
ExecStartPre=+/opt/myapp/bin/pre.sh
ExecStart=/opt/myapp/bin/myapp
ExecStop=/bin/kill -INT ${MAINPID}
ExecReload=/bin/kill -INT ${MAINPID} && /opt/myapp/bin/myapp
Restart=always
RestartSec=5
User=user
Group=user

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target mnt-sdcard.mount
```

I would like to wait `myapp` starting until `/mnt/sdcard` will be mounted.
But this service does not work well. When mount the media is delayed, the systemd throws `start condition failed` and does not retry.

```
# systemctl status myapp
● myapp.service - My App
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/myapp.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: inactive (dead)
Condition: start condition failed at Wed 2021-01-27 14:22:31 JST; 2h 35min ago
            ConditionPathIsMountPoint=/mnt/sdcard was not met
```

How can I make retry starting when start condition failed?

Answer (score 0):

in your prestart script have it check if the external media is mounted in a loop with delay

Answer (score 0):

If the sdcard is supposed to be mounted on boot, you can add below instead of the condition.

```
Requires=mnt-sdcard.mount
```

Remove `mnt-sdcard.mount` from `WantedBy`. Not sure what it does.